# I use react+webpack develop my website,but it always occur an error at render function,when i return <div></div>,

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

ERROR in `./component/header.jsx`

> Module build failed: SyntaxError:
>   C:/Users/zzl/Desktop/myWebsite/component/header.jsx: Unexpected token
>   (6:12)

```
  4 |     render(){
  5 |         return (
> 6 |             <div>
    |             ^
  7 |                 <li></li>
  8 |                 <li></li>
  9 |                 <li></li>
```

Comment: can you please add Header.jsx code?

Comment: You need to use the babel loader to transform JSX into javascript

Comment: Can you also add your webpack config file?